# Spring Transient Data Access Resource Exception in jdbcTemplate update

Tags: sql, spring, jdbc

I have a method to detect duplicate entry for a column:

(I inject to `jdbcTemplate` correctly)

```
private boolean isDuplicate(String username) {

    String sql = " select username from users where username=?";
    int result = jdbcTemplate.update(sql, new Object[]{username}, String.class);

    return result;
}
```

But i got this exception in runtime:

```
org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: 

PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [ select username from users where username=?]; Invalid argument value: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException; 

nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument value: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Comment: For start you don't `update` via the template, but `queryForObject`. Second, you return a username, hence `String`. Not int or boolean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the `queryForList()` method of `jdbcTemplate` like this:

```
results = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql,new Object[]{username},String.class);

if(results.isEmpty(){
  //no duplicate
}

else{
  //duplicate
}
```

Where `results` is a `List<String>`.